# Persistent WinSCP connection for batch copy in Python

Tags: python, copy, winscp

I'm trying to copy thousands files to a remote server. These files are generated in real-time within the script. I'm working on a Windows system and need to copy the files to a Linux server (hence the escaping).

I currently have:

```
import os
os.system("winscp.exe /console /command  \"option batch on\" \"option confirm off\" \"open user:pass@host\" \"put f1.txt /remote/dest/\"")
```

I'm using Python to generate the files but need a way to persist the remote connection so that I can copy each file, to the server, as it is generated (as opposed to creating a new connection each time). That way, I'll only need to change the field in the put option thus:

```
"put f2 /remote/dest"
"put f3 /remote/dest"
```

etc.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do this and found that code similar to this worked well:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

WINSCP = r'c:\<path to>\winscp.com'

class UploadFailed(Exception):
    pass

def upload_files(host, user, passwd, files):
    cmds = ['option batch abort', 'option confirm off']
    cmds.append('open sftp://{user}:{passwd}@{host}/'.format(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd))
    cmds.append('put {} ./'.format(' '.join(files)))
    cmds.append('exit\n')
    with Popen(WINSCP, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
               universal_newlines=True) as winscp: #might need shell = True here
        stdout, stderr = winscp.communicate('\n'.join(cmds))
    if winscp.returncode:
        # WinSCP returns 0 for success, so upload failed
        raise UploadFailed
```

This is simplified (and using Python 3), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an external program (winscp) you could also use an python ssh-library like [pyssh](http://pyssh.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: so how could i accomplish my task using pyssh?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to start persistent WinSCP sub-process in Python and feed the `put` commands to its standard input continuously.

I do not have Python example for this, but there's an equivalent JScript example:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation_advanced#inout
or C# example:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet#input

Though using WinSCP .NET assembly via its COM interface for Python would be a way easier:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library